# Custom positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

[Representation of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hn6z.png)

I've been trying to position the arrow at the bottom of the view port and place the contents under it... Thing is that both the arrow and the content exists within the same parent-element and I am not sure if i did good...I'm a beginner when it comes to website building and I've been scratching my head over this issue.

Here is the HTML and the CSS code:

```html
<div class="continut">
      <img src="img secundare\sageata-jos-n.png" alt="sageata in jos" id="sageata-jos">
      <!-- Buton dark mode -->
      <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <p>Mod intunecat</p>
       <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
         <div class="slider round"></div>
       </label>
     </div>
      <p>Rusia (în rusă Росси́я, transliterat: Rossia; pronunție rusă: /rɐˈsʲijə/), oficial Federația Rusă (în rusă Росси́йская Федера́ция, transliterat: Rossiiskaia Federația, pronunțat /rɐˈsʲijskəjə fʲɪdʲɪˈratsɨjə/), este o țară în Eurasia. Cu 17.125.200 km², Rusia este cea mai întinsă țară din lume, acoperind peste o optime din suprafața locuită a Pământului, și a noua ca populație, cu peste 144 de milioane de oameni în decembrie 2017, excluzând Crimeea. Aproximativ 77% din populație trăiește în partea vestică, europeană, a țării. Capitala Rusiei, Moscova, este unul dintre cele mai mari orașe din lume⁠; alte mari orașe⁠ sunt Sankt Petersburg, Novosibirsk, Ekaterinburg și Nijni Novgorod.</p>

      <p>Extinsă pe aproape toată Asia de Nord și pe o mare parte din Europa de Est, Rusia se întinde pe unsprezece fuse orare⁠ și cuprinde o gamă largă de tipuri de mediu⁠ și forme de relief. De la nord-vest spre sud-est, Rusia are frontiere terestre⁠ cu Norvegia, Finlanda, Estonia, Letonia, Lituania și Polonia (ambele cu Regiunea Kaliningrad), Belarus, Ucraina, Georgia, Azerbaidjan, Kazahstan, China, Mongolia și Coreea de Nord. Are frontiere maritime⁠ cu Japonia în Marea Ohotsk și cu SUA (statul Alaska) în Strâmtoarea Bering. </p>

      <p>Slavii răsăriteni au apărut ca grup identificabil în Europa între secolele al III-lea și al VIII-lea e.n.[11] Întemeiat și guvernat de o elită războinică varegă și de urmașii ei, statul medieval Rutenia a apărut în secolul al IX-lea. În 988, el a adoptat creștinismul ortodox de la Imperiul Bizantin,[12] începând o sinteză a culturilor bizantină și slavă care a definit cultura rusă⁠(d) în următorul mileniu.[12] Rutenia s-a dezintegrat în cele din urmă în mai multe state mici; majoritatea teritoriilor sale au fost apoi invadate de mongoli și au devenit tributare Hoardei de Aur nomade în secolul al XIII-lea.[13] Marele Cnezat al Moscovei a reunificat treptat principatele rusești din jur și a obținut independența față de Hoarda de Aur. Până în secolul al XVIII-lea, această țară își întinsese mult granițele prin cuceriri, anexări și explorări⁠(d), transformându-se în Imperiul Rus, al treilea imperiu ca întindere din istorie, din Polonia în vest până în Alaska⁠(d) în est.[14][15]</p>

      <p>După Revoluția Rusă, Republica Sovietică Federativă Socialistă Rusă a devenit principala și cea mai mare republică constituantă a Uniunii Republicilor Sovietice Socialiste, primul stat socialist prin constituție din lume.[16] Deși inițial aliată cu Germania Nazistă, Uniunea Sovietică a jucat un rol decisiv în victoria Aliaților în al Doilea Război Mondial,[17][18] din care a ieșit ca superputere mondială rivală cu Statele Unite în Războiul Rece. Epoca sovietică a adus unele dintre cele mai importante realizări tehnologice⁠(d) ale secolului al XX-lea, între care primul satelit artificial și lansarea primilor oameni în spațiu. Până la sfârșitul lui 1990, Uniunea Sovietică avea a doua economie a lumii, cea mai mare armată permanentă din lume și cel mai mare stoc de arme de distrugere în masă.[19][20][21] După dizolvarea Uniunii Sovietice în 1991, au apărut douăsprezece republici independente: Rusia, Ucraina, Belarus, Kazahstan, Uzbekistan, Armenia, Azerbaidjan, Georgia, Kîrgîzstan, Moldova, Tadjikistan, Turkmenistan, iar Statele Baltice anexate forțat și-au redobândit independența: Estonia, Letonia, Lituania; RSFS Rusă s-a reconstituit sub forma Federației Ruse și este recunoscută în dreptul internațional ca continuatoare a personalității legale și succesoare a Uniunii Sovietice⁠(d).[22] Este guvernată ca republică federală semiprezidențială. </p>

      <p>Economia rusă este a douăsprezecea ca mărime după PIB nominal și a șasea după paritatea puterii de cumpărare în 2015.[23] Bogatele resurse minerale și energetice ale Rusiei sunt cele mai mari din lume,[24] țara fiind unul dintre principalii producători de țiței⁠(d) și gaze naturale⁠(d) din lume.[25][26] Este una dintre cele cinci țări recunoscute ca deținătoare de arme nucleare și posedă cel mai mare arsenal de distrugere în masă.[27] Rusia se revendică mare putere și ca putere regională⁠(d) având ambiții de potențială superputere. Este membru permanent⁠(d) al Consiliului de Securitate al Națiunilor Unite și partener activ al ASEAN,[28][29][30] precum și membru al Organizației pentru Cooperare de la Shanghai, al G20, al Consiliului Europei, al Cooperării Economice Asia-Pacific (APEC), al Organizației pentru Securitate și Cooperare în Europa (OSCE), și al Organizației Mondiale a Comerțului (WTO), precum și membrul conducător al Comunității Statelor Independente (CSI), al Organizației Tratatului de Securitate Colectivă⁠(d) (CSTO) și unul din cei cinci membri ai Uniunii Economice Eurasiatice, împreună cu Armenia, Belarus, Kazahstan și Kîrgîzstan. </p>
    </div>
```

```css
div.continut{
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 20px;

  padding: 20px 10% 50px 10%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

The variables are for a dark/light theme switcher and the language is Romanian if you were wondering.
I don't care about the class names or ids

What I have managed to do so far was to position the arrow and contents correcly only for a specific screen resolution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        .hero-image {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;
        }

        .hero-image img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover
        }

        .arrow-down {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -8%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%)
        }
        .content{padding: 100px}
```

```html
 <div class="continut">
        <div class="hero-image">
            <img src="http://razu.me/stackO/bg.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="arrow-down">
                <img src="http://razu.me/stackO/arrow-down.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Heading Text</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab qui, iste perspiciatis natus quam dolores non adipisci, nobis pariatur cupiditate vitae consequatur accusamus illum ipsum, amet aspernatur consectetur? Adipisci repellat ipsam placeat porro soluta ea corporis, veritatis officiis facere illo voluptas, sunt quis tenetur minima repellendus quia. Explicabo commodi voluptates dicta consectetur, sequi ipsam atque, officiis eaque nulla deleniti possimus quaerat eligendi laudantium libero! Libero expedita quidem atque eius veniam, delectus nobis perferendis, placeat itaque sapiente aperiam repellendus! Quaerat atque eveniet expedita culpa, maxime incidunt quis nostrum harum fugit, iusto praesentium, rem unde deleniti dicta beatae eos maiores eligendi nisi.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell OP what you've done so they can learn from this code instead of copy/pasting your answer?